Setting a meshcollider's sharedmesh to a mesh which has been generated directly on the GPU gives "Failed extracting collision mesh"
I've been attempting to modify this example project
https://github.com/keijiro/ComputeMarchingCubes
I'm trying to repurpose it to build terrain. After the Update() method in Assets/NoiseField/NoiseFieldVisualizer.cs I want to set a MeshCollider's sharedMesh to use the mesh that's been generated.
All I've done is add a line after the mesh is set:
GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
Currently I get an error:
Failed extracting collision mesh because vertex at index 2817 contains a non-finite value (0.000000, -nan, 1.000000). Mesh asset path "" Mesh name ""
When I iterate over sharedMesh.vertices and log them to console, I get either (0, 0, 0) or (-431602100.00, -431602100.00, -431602100.00) for each vertex value. Presumably because the values haven't been sent back to the CPU?
I have mesh cleaning enabled for the MeshCollider.
Is it possible to generate a mesh collider with a GPU-only mesh? Preferably without transferring the points back to the CPU.

Collisions are processed on the CPU. How will you process collisions with this shape there without transferring points back to the CPU?

Do you know how to pull those values back to main memory?
